# FileProvider: Failed to find configured root

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying to share a pdf file, I set up the FileProvider like this:

On the main manifest xml:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

The res/xml/file_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

And in my code I am trying the following:

```
String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/file.pdf";
final Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileprovider", new File(path));
getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), data, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(data, "application/pdf").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Returns error:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/file.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation for `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) says that `<files-path>`:

> Represents files in the `files/` subdirectory of your app's internal storage area. This subdirectory is the same as the value returned by `Context.getFilesDir()`.

Your file is not in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). It is in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). For that, you need an `<external-path>` element, not a `<files-path>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but he didn't specify the API to use, so here it is.

```
 val imagePath = File(
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path +
            File.separator, "Your folder name"
)
val newfile = File(imagePath, "Your file name")


val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context,
    "com.example.domain.provider",
    newfile
)
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.type = "image/jpg" // set file type 
shareIntent.putExtra(
    Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    imageUri
)
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Status Saver Image"))
```

Happy Coding!